# Wordpress - Website was hacked and it is redirecting to some malicious website

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website running, but recently my website has been hacked. It is not even possible to enter my website: if I browse to my website it is redirected to some other website.

I have try to clean up the code and checked for any script inject but I couldn't locate the malicius script. How can I overcome this?

- I have tried to remove the unwanted Plugin
- I have tried to update all the plugins.
- I have tried to clean up all the files like functions.php,
  header.php, footer.php but there is no use of it and I couldn't
  locate the injected scripts.

Comment: Check the .htaccess file

Comment: spelling and formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scan the web-site on the local machine using software ai-bolit https://revisium.com/aibo/

1. create backup web-site
2. Download on local machine
3. unpack archive in folder ai-bolit

Notice: Do not unpack the archive into a directory with space character. For example,
C:\Documents and Settings\Michael\Downloads\aibolit-for-windows-en\ - will not work
C:\aibolit\ai-bolit-for-windows-en\ or d:\mysites\aibolit-for-windows\ - will work

For security website scan on your own

1. Unpack the backup archive of your website or place files which you want to check into the "site" folder
2. Run start.bat (for common check) or start_paranoid.bat (for "paranoid" check) to scan website files for viruses and hacker's scripts
3. Scanner will create AI-BOLIT-REPORT.html file upon completion

For malware analysis or website infection analysis by security experts ("paranoid" mode + quarantine file)
 
1. Unpack the backup archive of your site or place files which you want to check into the "site" folder
2. Run scan_and_quarantine.bat
3. AI-QUARANTINE-XXXXX.zip file and report AI-BOLIT-REPORT will be created upon completion (XXXXX is replaced by date and time numbers)
4. Send the file AI-QUARANTINE-XXXXX.zip to ai@revisium.com with the subject "Check the Report" for free malware analysis. 
The archive will contain everything experts need for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, install a wordpress security plugin ex. Wordfence. It will help you locate the malicious file in your public_html foolder and also lets you know if any of your file was modified.

Secondly, check your domain settings in your host. You can check to verify whether your domain is being redirected to other site.

Answer (score 1):

Check and do the below list.

1. check the file edition date inside file manager or FTP.
2. check .htaccess
3. check wp-config.php
4. check the content text inside posts and pages.
5. check inside uploads folder.
6. [Add Wordfence plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/)
7. [Add Anti-malware security plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue.

When accessing the website directly from the browser, it's working well and no redirect happens but when opening the website from Google search results, it redirects to another malicious website only the first time the URL opened. In the second time, no redirect happened.

After some digging, there was a plugin installed and hidden (not being displayed in plugins list) called `zend-fonts-wp`.

Using `Freesoul Deactivate Plugins` I disabled this plugin from being loaded and delete it permanently from plugins folder. I also deleted two database tables injected by this plugin called `wp_wusers_inputs` and `wp_wzen_time_table`.

Comment: I can't detect which plugin is causing this I've tried to uninstall everything, i noticed it also creates a cookie for first time visit "ht_rr=1" for admins and visitors, before redirecting it checks this cookie and if value is 1 it do not redirects,  i've added `document.cookie = "ht_rr=1; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2121 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";`   so that the value remains 1 and do not redirects the user, the redirect only occurs for one menu button click, some details of this malware is given here [link](https://blog.sucuri.net/2021/07/vulnerable-plugin-exploited-in-spam-redirect-campaign.html)

Answer (score 0):

Attackers use several ways to redirect the user

- Redirect users through malicious codes which they inject into the
  website
- Attackers might also execute .php codes
- Attackers can add themselves to your website as ghost admins
- By inserting codes in .htaccess/wp-config.php files
- By inserting JavaScript in WP plugin files

Check these files for the following malicious codes:

- Index.php
- Index.html 
  -.htaccess file

Theme files

1. Footer.php
2. Header.php
3. Functions.php

Helpful resources - https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/wordpress-hacked-redirect-wordpress-website-redirecting-to-malicious-pages/

https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/wordpress-files-hacked-wp-config-php-hack/

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem got the solution worked fine with 3 simple steps.

step 1. backup/zip all your files and folder of wordpress site

step 2. donwload and extract fresh wordpress (do not install)

step 3. replace wp-config.php and wp-content folder from the backup or was created in step 1.